# Using Java to pass variables to IBM Watson Conversation Dialog

Tags: java, watson-conversation, watson-dialog

I'm currently trying to integrate some Java code with a Watson Conversation Dialog. At the moment, I'm using the following code to pass a simple text input to the Watson dialog:

```
    MessageRequest emptyReq = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(" ").build();

    MessageResponse response1 = service.message(workspaceId, emptyReq).execute();

    MessageRequest req1 = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText("cancel my delivery").context(response1.getContext()).build();

    MessageResponse response2 = service.message(workspaceId, req1).execute();
```

This code works as intended and the response is correct. However, I'm unsure as to how I could pass variables in a message which would then be interpreted by the dialog.

For example, let's say that I store a date in a variable named "`estimatedDeliveryDate`".

I would send the message "*Cancel my delivery*" to Watson, along with `estimatedDeliveryDate` so that the dialog would respond with "*Your order due on `estimatedDeliveryDate` has now been cancelled*".

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Tooling, go to your node, click on the pencil to edit. Then add

```
"context": {
    "estimatedDeliveryDate": "today"
 }
```

Then on the output section you can write:

```
"output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Your reservation for  <? $estimatedDeliveryDate ?>  got canceled"
      ]
  }
```

Obviously, you can replace `today` with a dynamic value captured from the input. For that use `@sys-date`. See https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/conversation/system-entities.html